# Is this javascript property an instance property, or, a prototype property?

Tags: javascript, constructor, properties, prototype, instance

I give a property to a function, and use this function as a constructor, like this:

```
function h(){this.a='abc';}
h.high='2.0';
var hinst=new h();
function hasPrototypeProperty(object, name){
    return !object.hasOwnProperty(name) && (name in object);
}
console.log(h.hasOwnProperty('high'));    //true
console.log(hinst.hasOwnProperty('high'));//false
console.log(hasPrototypeProperty(hinst, 'high'));//false
console.log('a' in hinst);   //true
console.log('high' in hinst);//false
console.log(hinst.prototype.constructor.high);   //exception
```

Very weird, in my test, 'high' is neither an instance property

> hinst.hasOwnProperty)

or a prototype property

> hasPrototypeProperty(hinst,'high')

And the last line throws out an exception saying

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined

I suppose I have some miss understanding on property, how could 'hinst' visit 'high' property?

Comment: `high` is property of the constructor, so: `hinst.constructor.high` should return `"2.0"`. `hinst.constructor.hasOwnProperty('high')` => `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break things down a bit.

Here a *constructor function* is created. They are meant to be used with the `new` operator. A widespread convention is to capitalise the first letter to make that intention obvious.

```
function H(){ this.a='abc'; }
```

When the constructor function is invoked with `new`, something similar to this happens:

```
(function(){
    var o = Object.create( H.prototype );
    H.apply( o, arguments );
    return o;
}());
```

You basically end up with a new object (`{ a: 'abc' }`) that inherits from `H.prototype` object. That is, its' internal `[[Prototype]]` property<sup>1</sup> points to it.

`H.prototype` is initially an object with a single property (`constructor` which points to constructor function `H`), but you can freely replace or extend it. Which is what you probably wanted to do with this line:

```
H.high='2.0';
```

But instead, you added the property to the constructor function `H` (functions are objects too).

```
console.log( H.hasOwnProperty('high') );                //true
console.log( (new H()).hasOwnProperty('high') );        //false
console.log( (new H()).hasPrototypeProperty('high') );  //false
```

---

Corrected example.

```js
function H(){ this.a='abc'; }
H.prototype.high='2.0';
var hinst = new H();
function hasPrototypeProperty(object, name){
  return !object.hasOwnProperty(name) && (name in object);
}
console.log(H.hasOwnProperty('high'));            //false
console.log(hinst.hasOwnProperty('high'));        //false
console.log(H.prototype.hasOwnProperty('high'));  //true
console.log(hasPrototypeProperty(hinst, 'high')); //true
console.log('a' in hinst);                        //true
console.log('high' in hinst);                     //true
console.log(H.prototype.high);                    //2.0
console.log(hinst.high);                          //2.0
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Inheritance and the prototype chain at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Answer (score 1):

Here `h` is a object of type `function` to which you assigned a `property` named `high`. So it is not related to instance or prototype.

Comment: Still a bit confused, then how could I make "hinst" visit "high" property?

Comment: @Troskyvs: Put it on `h.prototype.high`, not `h.high`! Instances inherit from the prototype, not from the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

There's some confusion in your code between constructors and prototypes

```
console.log(inst.prototype.constructor.high); // exception
console.log(inst.constructor.high); // '2.0'
```

because  your constructor is not part of the prototype chain.

When you define properties after the fact on constructors (which are just 
functions) then you end up with this

```
function h () {
this.a='abc';
}
h.high='2.0';
console.log(h);
// => { [Function: h] high: '2.0' }
```

a Frankenstein function-object monster.